# FileWriter is not writing anything into the file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

I programmed a little game that also has a highscore being displayed when the game is over.

The highscore is saved into a integer variable simply called `highscore`.

Now I am trying to safe the highscore into a file to avoid it being reset everytime you close the app.

My approach was using a FileWriter as you can see below. The game is still running smoothly and everything is fine I don't get any errors etc. but it does not safe anything into the file.

I just don't understand why.

Thankful for any help.

```
 private void saveHighscore() {
        File highscoreFile = new File("C:\\Users\\FuadM\\Desktop\\Mueckenfang\\Highscore.txt");
        try (FileWriter highscoreWriter = new FileWriter(highscoreFile)) {

            if (!highscoreFile.exists()) {
                highscoreFile.createNewFile();
            }
            highscoreWriter.write("" + highscore);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I just checked and I am getting this message in the terminal:

```
    W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    C:\Users\FuadM\Desktop\Mueckenfang\Highscore.txt: open failed: EROFS
    (Read- only file system)
```

Comment: Your code works for me. On my Mac I get a nice new file with a number in it. Is any stack trace printed from your code? If so, please paste it into the question (nicely formatted as code).

Comment: Why double slashes?

Comment: @cutiko - A backslash is a meta-character and therefore you need an extra backslash to escape it.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for your comment. I just did edit my question.

Comment: *"open failed: EROFS  (Read-only file system)"* - You can't write to a read-only file system.

Comment: I am fairly new to this and never had an error like this before. How do I solve this?

Comment: You have this question tagged as `android`, but your path is for Windows. Are you developing an Android app or a Windows program?

Comment: I am developing an Android app using Android Studio.

Comment: *EROFS (Enhanced Read-Only File System) is a lightweight read-only file system …* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EROFS)). How your C drive (or just part of it) can be read-only, I don’t understand.

Comment: @OleV.V. Because OP is running this on android, or in the android emulator :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot I read your answer and understood that the program tries to write to an Andorid file system where there isn’t any C drive at all, so the mere presence of `C:\` first in the path ensured that this would fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android doesn't have a C: drive, or a desktop, or a Mueckenfang directory. I'm not quite sure what your thought process was, but your phone is certainly not going to be capable of writing files on your PC's desktop.

You can write to files on Android, but that's not what you should be doing here. Android apps ship with SQLite (a simple database system) built in, and that's where a game should be storing a high score. I think your next step should be to search the web for a tutorial on how to do SQLite from Android.

Comment: Shared preferences is ok and much easier. And a file is ok too. Just the path is wrong.

Comment: I did a little research on SQLite and after watching some tutorials and trying to store the highscore inside a small database, I finally had what I wanted to have. Thank you. Just thought using a simple file would be an easier approach for beginners.